# Why does this for loop in Javascript give me a number instead of the list of numbers from 0 to 4?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I know that the normal behavior of a for loop is similar to this:

```
for(let i = 0; i<5; i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

which gives me this result:
0

1

2

3

4

However the following code gives me a 5 as a result and I do not know why it doesn't give me a result similar to the example above.It doesn't behave as a for loop because it doesn't have into account the initializer. Thanks a lot for your help.

```
 function charCount(str){

    for(var i=2;i<=str.length;i++){
        result = [i]
    }
    return result; 
}
charCount('hello')
```

Comment: `result=result` does not do anything.

Comment: sorry, I edited it, it was result = [i]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function charCount(str) {
    result=[];
    for(var i=2;i<=str.length;i++){
        result.push(i);
    }
    return result; 
}
charCount('hello')
```

When doing result=[i], you are just resetting whole array, push() appends i to the existing array in every iteration.

Comment: @MauricioAriza See this on what to do when you find an answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Got it. I will give points when I reach 15. Because I'm new here and I only have 10 points.

Answer (score 1):

This code return "5" because

In your code you return last  value of result

for example you pass string "hello" then for loop iterate 2 to 5(str.length) so in the last result variable has a value as 5 so when you return result valriable it return 5.

for returning all number 0 to 5 then modify your code

result.push(i)

so every time number store iin result list and in the last you return that list

Answer (score 1):

You can also iterate through the count and push the values into a new array using the keys without `.push()` by referencing the key in a bracket within the for loop. By assigning the arrays key value with a bracket before you define the next value, you are ensuring that you are iterating through to a new key\value pair inside the array with each iteration up to the str length.

```js
function charCount(str) {
    result=[];
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        result[i] = i;
    }
    return result; 
}
console.log(charCount('hello'))
```

Also consider the following code using a forEach loop where you can define your key/value pairs for parsing within the loop...

```js
function charCount(str) {
    result=[];
    str = str.split(''); // split the string 
    str.forEach(function(value, index){
      result[index] = value;
      // or result[index] = index --> to push in the numbered values of the keys as values to the array --> [0,1,2,3,4];
    })
    return result; 
}
console.log(charCount('hello'))
```